# wxBusyInfo Alternative in wxWidgets 2.8

Tags: c++, dialog, wxwidgets, disabled-input, busyindicator

I'm running wxWidgets 2.8 and I need to disable my GUI while I'm waiting for an update from my business logic.

I set out to use [`wxBusyInfo`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_busy_info.html) but I was disappointed to find that it is only in wxWidgets 3.1.

In 2.8 what is the best way to pop up a dialog which disables user input until a signal is received from the business logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wxWindowDisabler` with an info window of your choice.

OR

You can copy the files for `wxBusyInfo` from 3.1 to your project. They need only minor adjustment (like the include list) but other than that they look pretty self contained.
Just for the record, it is there since 2.9.0, only that particular constructor is since 3.1.